# Trying to add a group to a group

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, wordpress

I have a server which has all of its users under their own user:group for example the user somename has a folder /home/somename and is chowned somename:somename.

Now, it seems that this user has a problem updating their Wordpress from the web and it keeps on asking for FTP details. I've traced the issue into the fact that www-data doesn't have access to the users files.

```
http://ardeearam.com/solved-wordpress-asking-for-ftp-credentials-when-upgrading/
...sudo chown -R www-data wordpress/...
```

How do I allow or add www-data into somename privileges?

Comment: Where are their wordpress files located? I assume in some directory under their home directory, but the ideas I have depend on a specific directory location.

Answer (score -1):

In the 1970's world of **/etc/passwd** and **/etc/group** security, only a uid (user) can belong / be added to a group, no nesting is supported, but you could run something along the following lines, as a work around (assumes the **wordpress** directories are off the users home):

```
sudo bash
ls -d /home/* | xargs chmod o+rx
find /home/ -type d -name 'wordpress' | xargs chgrp -R www-data
find /home/ -type d -name 'wordpress' | xargs chmod -R g+rw
```

Which has the side effect of allowing all users to look in the home directory of any other user.

Alternatively you could add the **wwwrun** user id (change to suit) to the personal group of every user with a wordpress directory e.g.

```
sudo bash
for wpDir in `find /home -type d -name 'wordpress'`
do 
  chgrp -R www-data $wpDir && chmod -R g+rw $wpDir
  wpUser=$(echo $wpDir|sed 's:/[^/]*/\([^/]*\)/.*$:\1:')
  grep $wpUser /etc/passwd > /dev/null && ( usermod -a -G $wpUser wwwrun; chmod g+rx /home/$wpUser)
done
```